# How to Append Value to an Array from Input Text in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

I'm finding DOM manipulation tricky. I have written a function that uses the filter method on an array with numbers that are divisible by two.

The function `evenNums` works. I want to use the `push()` method to push numbers from the input text field to the array and display the result from the function `evenNums` on the page.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> </head>
  <body>
    <label for="text">Enter Text</label>
    <input id="myText" type="text" />

    <input type="radio" />
    <label for="function">Function 1</label>

    <input type="radio" />
    <label for="function">Function 2</label>

    <button id="btn">Click Me</button>

    <div id="result"></div>

    <script src="array.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

ignore the radio buttons. This is my Javascript

```
const inputBtn = document.getElementById("btn")
const myText = document.getElementById("myText")
const result = document.getElementById("result")

//function 1 filter method on array. 
const nums = [1,2,3];
const answer = nums.filter(evenNums);  

function evenNums(nums) {

  if (nums%2 == 0) {
      return nums
        
  }  
  }
  result.innerHTML = answer;
  console.log(nums) // original array 
  console.log(answer) // array using filter method



//How do I push a value from the user to the array?  
inputBtn.addEventListener ("click", function() {

   nums.push(myText.value); 
   myText.value ='';
   evenNums(nums);

  });
```

This is how far I've got. How do I push a value from the user to the array and display it on the page? Am I close?

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is almost correct, just make sure you call the `filter` and set the `textcontent` when clicking the button. Also the `value` is a string, you will have to `parseInt()` it to do the even / odd calculation. It is also safer to use `textcontent` instead of `innerHTML`.

```js
const inputBtn = document.getElementById("btn")
const myText = document.getElementById("myText")
const result = document.getElementById("result")

const nums = [1, 2, 3];
inputBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  nums.push(parseInt(myText.value));
  myText.value = '';
  const answer = nums.filter(evenNums);
  function evenNums(nums) {
    if (nums % 2 == 0) {
      return nums
    }
  }
  result.textContent = answer;
});
```

```html
<label for="text">Enter Text</label>
<input id="myText" type="text" />
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Just a sidenote: `filter()` expects a boolean as `return` value, the reason your filter works is because you `return nums` which is seen as [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

This should be better.

```js
const nums = [1, 2, 3];
const answer = nums.filter(evenNums);

function evenNums(nums) {
  if (nums % 2 == 0) {
    return true;
  }
}

console.log(answer);
```

You could simplify your filter to.

```js
const nums = [1,2,3];
const answer = nums.filter(n => n % 2 === 0);  

console.log(answer);
```

Because (`x === y`) returns a boolean.

The short answer would be.

```js
const inputBtn = document.getElementById("btn")
const myText = document.getElementById("myText")
const result = document.getElementById("result")

const nums = [1, 2, 3];
inputBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  nums.push(parseInt(myText.value));
  myText.value = '';
  result.textContent = nums.filter(n => n % 2 === 0);
});
```

```html
<label for="text">Enter Text</label>
<input id="myText" type="text" />
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are on the right track. After you push the user's input to the array, you can display the result of filtered array on the page by setting the `innerHTML` attribute.

Just calling the function on its own is not going to do anything for you.

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = nums.filter(evenNums);
```